# Is it possible to power an ATTiny85 and a 6N138 through MIDI in?

Tags: power-supply, attiny85, midi

I'm working on a MIDI2CV board.

The schematic I'm working on is provided by [the website of Kevin's Blog.](https://emalliab.wordpress.com/tag/midi2cv/)

The MIDI cable comes the MIDI out of a  Digitakt. It has 5V on pin5.

I was wondering if it is ok to connect the pin5 net to the global 5V of the circuit to avoid powering with external 5V like that.

[image: MIDI2CV scheme]

Answer (score 1):

No. For many reasons. It's just wrong, against MIDI standard, breaks isolation which allows for ground loops and would not even provide much power. If you say but other people use it too, well, they should not as technically that device does not comply with MIDI standard and therefore it will not be a MIDI device, and is not expected to work with actual MIDI devices.

First of all, the pins on connector are  not called MIDI IN or MIDI out.

And there is usually no 5V on pin 5. Most often it is an open drain pin. Very rarely a MIDI output might use a TTL or CMOS output which pulls the pin high. And it is not intended to draw current from this pin.

There is 5V on pin 4, but pin 4 is connected to 5V ia 220 ohm resistor, not directly. So it can't be used for much power. It is used to provide a current source for the optoisolator LED.

And if you did use it for power, which it shouldn't, you would have to use pin 2 as ground. But this also means that the optoisolator becomes rather useless for isolation.

So even if it could be used, there is not enough power to do anything useful with it, and voltage will drop during data transmission.

Comment: I'm already using a product from midisolutions powered trough MIDI connections, and it works great. They explain that in their FAQ (https://www.midisolutions.com/faqs.htm).
So why a commercial product use this technique and it's working ?
Here some people discuss about powering over MIDI with the Digitakt
(https://www.elektronauts.com/t/power-over-midi/61983)

Comment: I knew it. Let me explain again : Yes, these products exist. But they should not exist. Anyone can make a product that should not exist. If you read the web page carefully, it does not always work and not under all conditions. The product is not made according to MIDI specification and so it does not have to work with MIDI devices and it might not be officially/legally called a MIDI device. It just happens to work in some occasions under some conditions.

Comment: Ok I understand. This project is for my personal use only, could I connect the pin 5 to the reference +5V in order to get it working ?

Comment: You can try if you want to - just don't expect it to work. I know none of the MIDI devices I have output 5V on pin 5 so I would not even try it.

Comment: pin4 i wanted to say sorry

Comment: Pin 4 may work better. But it does not work with just pin 4, you need pin 2 for ground too. And diode to allow MCU to be powered while data wire is pulled low. And capacitor. And maybe a boost converter to keep MCU supply stable when data is being transmitted or it will drop. As MIDI is a 5mA current loop, it can't provide a lot of current, even a short circuit will get you max 22mA which is almost nothing.

Comment: Rather than "should not exist" I would say that by going off the official specifications you are doing things at your own risk (of things not working). There's no police and you won't shock yourself. The point of the rules is so everything works together nicely. Products that power themselves from MIDI are bending the rules and there is a chance they might not work in some systems. Instead of saying "if you do this it won't work with certain keyboards or mixers" they'd rather say "don't do this" so that your product *will* work with all keyboards or mixers.

Comment: @user253751 The user who buys may not understand it's not a device made according to standard or specification and may not understand why it does not work or damages your device when used. Like USB A to A cables are non-standard, allowed only if power wire is not connected, yet USB A to A cables with power wire connected exists and people fry their computers with them. So rule bending is a problem.

Comment: yes, devices which bend rules should be treated as low-quality garbage products. A lot of DIY stuff is also low-quality garbage and works fine for the specific situation it is in.

Answer (score -2):

The digital pin idles at 5V, rather than this being a connection to a 5V supply that you can use. [image: image showing midi transfer] 
Image from https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/midi-tutorial/hardware--electronic-implementation

I've also seen diagrams showing pin 4 also connected via pullup to 5V, but not a direct connection. You can't use this to power your device.

Comment: For a real MIDI device, the pin will not be expected to idle at 5V. MIDI devices don't define the output stage, and many use open drain output so if it works at all, it will only work with a few MIDI devices, and even then, the logic output should not be used to power arbitrary devices, as devices don't expect current to be sucked out from data pin.